# Effect of increasing volume on gas-phase equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

$$\ce{P4(s) + 6F2(g) <=> 4PF3(g)}$$

If the volume of the system was increased and has now re-established equilibrium which of the following would NOT be correct?

a) The mass of $\ce{P4}$ would not have changed.

b) The concentration of $\ce{F2}$ would have decreased.

c) The number of moles of $\ce{PF3}$ would have decreased.

d) The number of moles of $\ce{F2}$ would have increased.

The answers say c; please help explain how they got this.

Comment: it depends, decreased from when? Is it referring to the decrease immediately after volume change or from the previous equilibrium?

Comment: look again, it should be B in the latter case. None are right in the former case

Comment: Why is no one closing this question as "off-topic" as the problem poster as shown no attempt in providing his own insight? Just curious because it seems to me that's usually what happens to this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply Le Chatelier's Principle, which states that if a dynamic equilibrium is disturbed by changing the conditions, the position of equilibrium moves to counteract the change.

In this case, when the volume of the system is increased, the pressure of the system decreases. To increase the pressure of the system, the system would have to favour the side of the equation with more gaseous molecules. Thus, the position of equilibrium shifts to the left, increasing the number of gaseous molecules of fluorine and decreasing the number of phosphorous trifluoride molecules, resulting in an overall increase in gaseous molecules in the system, increasing the pressure of the system, to counteract the decrease in pressure. As a result, more phosphorus molecules would be produced.

Thus, A is incorrect. However, B is also incorrect as a bigger amount of fluorine molecules in the system would naturally lead to an increase in its concentration, as the other gas phosphorus trifluoride decreases.

I conclude that your question is problematic.